# Creating screensavers in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am brand new to Xamarin and OS X development in general, and am hoping to use Xamarin.Mac to port a screensaver to OS X. Unfortunately I cannot find any examples or suggestions that this can be done in Xamarin, or whether I will need to use Objective-C / Swift (and therefore rewrite my otherwise platform-agnostic C# code).

It appears the primary glue for OS X screensavers is the abstract  [ScreenSaverView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screensaver/screensaverview) class - would it be theoretically possible to bind to `ScreenSaver.framework`? Or is construction of screensavers / system plugins a completely different beast which just isn't supported?